# CSF types in humans

Tags: human-physiology, central-nervous-system

There are several blood types such as A, B and O. Crossing these blood types such as in a transfusion, the results can be fatal. Along these lines, issues can arise when an organ or bone marrow are placed in a new host, issues can arise if certain markers aren't met.

With these examples in mind, are there multiples types of CerebroSpinal Fluid (CSF)?

In attempting to research this subject, I did not find anything answering this question, included is an article discussing CSF, but not mentioning different types of CSF. [Science Direct Article on CSF](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/medicine-and-dentistry/cerebrospinal-fluid)

Comment: https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/94/5198

Comment: @David: Thanks for the edit.